# Chapman-Kolmogorov family uniquely determined by linear operators?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a locally compact polish space, $(P_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Chapman-Kolmogorov family on $E$ and $B(E,\mathbb{R})$ be the bounded measurable functions from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ . Define the linear operator

$$
\bar{P}_t:B(E,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow B(E,\mathbb{R}), P_tf(x)=\int_\mathbb{E}f(y)P_t(x,dy).
$$

**Question:** Is $(P_t)$ already uniquely determined by $\bar{P}_t\mid_{C_0(E,\mathbb{R})}$?

I know that it's uniquely determined by $(\bar{P}_t)$ as $P_t(x,A)=(\bar{P}_t\mathbb{1_A})(x)$ for $x \in E, A \in \mathcal{B}(E)$, but I am not sure about the restriction.

Comment: What do you mean by $C_0(E,\Bbb R)$ for a Polish space $E$?

Comment: The continuous functions from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at infinity.

Comment: Does one also have to assume that $E$ is locally compact?

Comment: That's one  context for "vanishing at infinity" to have a useful meaning.

Comment: Sorry, I add that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two probability measures on a Polish space $E$ coincide on $\mathcal B(E)$ once their integrals assign the same values to each function in $C_b(E,\Bbb R)$, for example.  Thus for each $x\in E$ and each $t\ge 0$, the probability measure $P_t(x,\cdot)$ is determined by  $\bar P_t|_{C_b(E,\Bbb R)}$.

And $C_0(E,\Bbb R)$ is enough in the locally compact case.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know where I can find a proof of that?

Comment: Using $\mu$ and $\nu$ for the two probability measures in question, you can  apply the monotone class theorem (Theorem 1 here: https://almostsuremath.com/2019/10/27/the-functional-monotone-class-theorem/) with $\mathcal K$ there taken to be $C_b(E,\Bbb R)$ and $\mathcal H$ taken to be the class of bounded Borel measurable functions $f$ for which $\int_E f d\mu=\int_E f d\nu$.

Comment: Sorry, one more question: When you know that $\int f d\mu=\int f d\nu$ for $f \in C_b(E,\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow\mu=\nu$ how do you get  $\int f d\mu=\int f d\nu$ for $f \in C_0(E,\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow\mu=\nu$. I'd like to get the second assertion from the first.